# Rally - CA Agile Central - How do I read stories that are already DONE?

Tags: rally

When looking for stories in Rally - CA Agile Central - how do I read stories that are already DONE?

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer to my own question:

You can use either the Plan -> User Stories to filter by the ScheduleState (and choose 'Accepted') or you can also choose the Plan -> Work Views page where you can choose the project/s then choose to display user stories and then include a similar filter on ScheduleState.